# C# like List<T> in VBA

Tags: c#, vba, collections

I'd like to create a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6sh2ey19.aspx) on VBA like you create on C#, there is any way I can do that? I looked for questions about it here on SO, but I could not find any.

Comment: I found a way to use your custom list in a `For Each` loop just like you would use a collection, and also to get items with `myList(index)` like you would use an array - see updated answer. Works in VB6 but if you export your .cls, edit it in notepad and reimport it back into tour VBA project it should work just as well :)

Comment: Use [ArrayList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.7.2) if you're OK with a linked list of objects (not strong typed). Use like this `Set MyList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")`.
You can also leverage a collection or dictionary to get list functionality. See the answers below for implementation details.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Generics appeared in C# 2.0; in VB6/VBA the closest you get is a `Collection`. Lets you `Add`, `Remove` and `Count`, but you'll need to wrap it with your own class if you want more functionality, such as `AddRange`, `Clear` and `Contains`.

`Collection` takes any `Variant` (i.e. anything you throw at it), so you'll have to enforce the `<T>` by verifying the type of  the item(s) being added. The `TypeName()` function would probably be useful for this.

---

I took the challenge :)

**Updated** [see original code here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19148804/3)

### List.cls

Add a new class module to your VB6/VBA project. This will define the functionality of `List<T>` we're implementing. As [Santosh]'s answer shows we're a little bit restricted in our selection of *what* collection structure we're going to wrap. We could do with arrays, but collections being objects make a better candidate, since we want an enumerator to use our `List` in a `For Each` construct.

#### Type Safety

The thing with `List<T>` is that `T` says *this list is a list of what type exactly*, and the constraint implies once we determine the type of `T`, that list instance sticks to it. In VB6 we can use `TypeName` to get a string representing the name of the type we're dealing with, so my approach would be to make the list *know* the name of the type it's holding at the very moment the first item is added: what C# does declaratively in VB6 we can implement as a runtime thing. But this is VB6, so let's not go crazy about preserving type safety of numeric value types - I mean we can be smarter than VB6 here all we want, at the end of the day it's not C# code; the language isn't very stiff about it, so a compromise could be to only allow implicit type conversion on numeric types of a smaller size than that of the first item in the list.

```vb
Private Type tList
    Encapsulated As Collection
    ItemTypeName As String
End Type
Private this As tList
Option Explicit

Private Function IsReferenceType() As Boolean
    If this.Encapsulated.Count = 0 Then IsReferenceType = False: Exit Function
    IsReferenceType = IsObject(this.Encapsulated(1))
End Function

Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Attribute NewEnum.VB_Description = "Gets the enumerator from encapsulated collection."
    Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
    Attribute NewEnum.VB_MemberFlags = "40"

    Set NewEnum = this.Encapsulated.[_NewEnum]
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set this.Encapsulated = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set this.Encapsulated = Nothing
End Sub
```

Verifying if the value is of the appropriate type can be the role of a function that can be made `public` for convenience, so a value can be tested to be valid by client code, before it's actually added. Every time we initialize a `New List`, `this.ItemTypeName` is an empty string for that instance; the rest of the time we're probably going to see the correct type, so let's not bother checking all possibilities (not C#, evaluation won't break at the first `Or` that follows a `true` statement):

```vb
Public Function IsTypeSafe(value As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = this.ItemTypeName = vbNullString Or this.ItemTypeName = TypeName(value)
    If result Then GoTo QuickExit

    result = result _
        Or this.ItemTypeName = "Integer" And StringMatchesAny(TypeName(value), "Byte") _
        Or this.ItemTypeName = "Long" And StringMatchesAny(TypeName(value), "Integer", "Byte") _
        Or this.ItemTypeName = "Single" And StringMatchesAny(TypeName(value), "Long", "Integer", "Byte") _
        Or this.ItemTypeName = "Double" And StringMatchesAny(TypeName(value), "Long", "Integer", "Byte", "Single") _
        Or this.ItemTypeName = "Currency" And StringMatchesAny(TypeName(value), "Long", "Integer", "Byte", "Single", "Double")

QuickExit:
    IsTypeSafe = result
End Function
```

Now that's a start.

So we have a `Collection`. That buys us `Count`, `Add`, `Remove`, and `Item`. Now the latter is interesting, because it's also the `Collection`'s *default property*, and in C# it would be called an *indexer* property. In VB6 we set the `Item.VB_UserMemId` attribute to 0 and we get a *default property*:

```vb
Public Property Get Item(ByVal index As Long) As Variant
    Attribute Item.VB_Description = "Gets/sets the item at the specified index."
    Attribute Item.VB_UserMemId = 0

    If IsReferenceType Then
        Set Item = this.Encapsulated(index)
    Else
        Item = this.Encapsulated(index)
    End If
End Property
```

#### Procedure Attributes

In VBA the IDE does not provide any way of editing those, but you can edit the code in Notepad and import the edited .cls file into your VBA project. In VB6 you have a Tools menu to edit those:

[image: procedure attributes]
[image: procedure attributes]

`Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4` tells VB to use this property to provide an enumerator - we're just passing it that of the encapsulated `Collection`, and it being a hidden property it begins with an underscore (don't try this at home!). `Attribute NewEnum.VB_MemberFlags = "40"` is supposed to make it a hidden property as well, but I haven't yet figured out why VB won't pick up on that one. So in order to call the getter for that hidden property, we need to surround it with `[]` square brackets, because an identifier can't legally start with an underscore in VB6/VBA.

> One nice thing about the `NewEnum.VB_Description` attribute is that whatever description you enter there, shows up in the *Object Browser* (<kbd>F2</kbd>) as a description/mini-documentation for your code.

#### Item Accessors / "Setters"

The VB6/VBA `Collection` doesn't allow directly writing values into its items. We can assign *references*, but not *values*. We can implement a write-enabled `List` by providing setters for the `Item` property - because we don't know if our `T` will be a value or a reference/object, we'll provide both `Let` and `Set` accessors. Since `Collection` doesn't support this we're going to have to first remove the item at the specified index, and then insert the new value at that place.

Good news, `RemoveAt` and `Insert` are two methods we're going to have to implement anyway, and `RemoveAt` comes for free because its semantics are the same as those of the encapsulated `Collection`:

```vb
Public Sub RemoveAt(ByVal index As Long)
    this.Encapsulated.Remove index
End Sub

Public Sub RemoveRange(ByVal Index As Long, ByVal valuesCount As Long)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = Index To Index + valuesCount - 1
        RemoveAt Index
    Next
End Sub
```

My implementation of `Insert` feels like it could get much better, but it essentially reads as "grab everything *after* the specified index, make a copy; remove everything after the specified index; add the specified value, add back the rest of the items":

```vb
Public Sub Insert(ByVal index As Long, ByVal value As Variant)
    Dim i As Long, isObjRef As Boolean
    Dim tmp As New List

    If index > Count Then Err.Raise 9  'index out of range

    For i = index To Count
        tmp.Add Item(i)
    Next

    For i = index To Count
        RemoveAt index
    Next

    Add value
    Append tmp

End Sub
```

`InsertRange` can take a `ParamArray` so we can supply inline values:

```vb
Public Sub InsertRange(ByVal Index As Long, ParamArray values())
    Dim i As Long, isObjRef As Boolean
    Dim tmp As New List

    If Index > Count Then Err.Raise 9  'index out of range

    For i = Index To Count
        tmp.Add Item(i)
    Next

    For i = Index To Count
        RemoveAt Index
    Next

    For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
        Add values(i)
    Next
    Append tmp

End Sub
```

`Reverse` has nothing to do with sorting, so we can implement it right away:

```vb
Public Sub Reverse()
    Dim i As Long, tmp As New List

    Do Until Count = 0
        tmp.Add Item(Count)
        RemoveAt Count
    Loop

    Append tmp

End Sub
```

Here I thought, since VB6 doesn't support *overloads*. that it would be nice to have a method that can *add all items from another list*, so I called that `Append`:

```vb
Public Sub Append(ByRef values As List)
    Dim value As Variant, i As Long
    For i = 1 To values.Count
        Add values(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

`Add` is where our `List` becomes more than just an encapsulated `Collection` with a couple extra methods: if it's the first item being added to the list, we have a piece of logic to execute here - not that I don't care about how many items there are in the encapsulated collection, so if all items are removed from the list the type of `T` remains constrained:

```vb
Public Sub Add(ByVal value As Variant)
    If this.ItemTypeName = vbNullString Then this.ItemTypeName = TypeName(value)
    If Not IsTypeSafe(value) Then Err.Raise 13, ToString, "Type Mismatch. Expected: '" & this.ItemTypeName & "'; '" & TypeName(value) & "' was supplied." 'Type Mismatch
    this.Encapsulated.Add value
End Sub
```

The source of the error raised when `Add` fails is the result of a call to `ToString`, a method that returns... the name of the type, *including the type of T* - so we can make it a `List<T>` instead of a `List(Of T)`:

```vb
Public Function ToString() As String
    ToString = TypeName(Me) & "<" & Coalesce(this.ItemTypeName, "Variant") & ">"
End Function
```

`List<T>` allows adding many items at once. At first I implemented `AddRange` with an array of values for a parameter, but then with usage it occurred to me that again, this isn't C#, and taking in a `ParamArray` is much, much more handy:

```vb
Public Sub AddRange(ParamArray values())
    Dim value As Variant, i As Long
    For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
        Add values(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

...And then we get to those `Item` setters:

```vb
Public Property Let Item(ByVal index As Long, ByVal value As Variant)
    RemoveAt index
    Insert index, value
End Property

Public Property Set Item(ByVal index As Long, ByVal value As Variant)
    RemoveAt index
    Insert index, value
End Property
```

Removing an item by providing a value instead of an index, would require another method that gives us the index of that value, and because we're not only supporting *value types* but also *reference types*, this is going to be very fun, because now we need a way to determine *equality* between reference types - we can get *reference equality* by comparing `ObjPtr(value)`, but we're going to need more than just that - the .net framework taught me about `IComparable` and `IEquatable`. Let's just cram these two interfaces into one and call it `IComparable` - *yes, you can write and implement interfaces in VB6/VBA*.

### IComparable.cls

Add a new class module and call it `IComparable` - if you really plan to use them for something else then you could put them in two separate class modules and call the other one `IEquatable`, but that would make you two interfaces to implement instead of one, for all reference types you want to be able to work with.

**This isn't mock-up code, all that's needed is the method signatures**:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Function CompareTo(other As Variant) As Integer
'Compares this instance with another; returns one of the following values:
'   -1 if [other] is smaller than this instance.
'    1 if [other] is greater than this instance.
'    0 otherwise.
End Function

Public Function Equals(other As Variant) As Boolean
'Compares this instance with another; returns true if the two instances are equal.
End Function
```

### List.cls

#### Putting the IComparable interface to use

Given that we have packed our `IComparable` with `CompareTo` and `Equals`, we can now find the index of any value in our list; we can also determine if the list *contains* any specified value:

```vb
Public Function IndexOf(value As Variant) As Long
    Dim i As Long, isRef As Boolean, comparable As IComparable
    isRef = IsReferenceType
    For i = 1 To this.Encapsulated.Count
        If isRef Then
            If TypeOf this.Encapsulated(i) Is IComparable And TypeOf value Is IComparable Then
                Set comparable = this.Encapsulated(i)
                If comparable.Equals(value) Then
                    IndexOf = i
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Else
                'reference type isn't comparable: use reference equality
                If ObjPtr(this.Encapsulated(i)) = ObjPtr(value) Then
                    IndexOf = i
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        Else
            If this.Encapsulated(i) = value Then
                IndexOf = i
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next
    IndexOf = -1
End Function

Public Function Contains(value As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim v As Variant, isRef As Boolean, comparable As IComparable
    isRef = IsReferenceType
    For Each v In this.Encapsulated
        If isRef Then
            If TypeOf v Is IComparable And TypeOf value Is IComparable Then
                Set comparable = v
                If comparable.Equals(value) Then Contains = True: Exit Function
            Else
                'reference type isn't comparable: use reference equality
                If ObjPtr(v) = ObjPtr(value) Then Contains = True: Exit Function
            End If
        Else
            If v = value Then Contains = True: Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

The `CompareTo` method comes into play when we start asking what the `Min` and `Max` values might be:

```vb
Public Function Min() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, isRef As Boolean
    Dim smallest As Variant, isSmaller As Boolean, comparable As IComparable

    isRef = IsReferenceType
    For i = 1 To Count

        If isRef And IsEmpty(smallest) Then
            Set smallest = Item(i)
        ElseIf IsEmpty(smallest) Then
            smallest = Item(i)
        End If

        If TypeOf Item(i) Is IComparable Then
            Set comparable = Item(i)
            isSmaller = comparable.CompareTo(smallest) < 0
        Else
            isSmaller = Item(i) < smallest
        End If

        If isSmaller Then
            If isRef Then
                Set smallest = Item(i)
            Else
                smallest = Item(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If isRef Then
        Set Min = smallest
    Else
        Min = smallest
    End If

End Function

Public Function Max() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, isRef As Boolean
    Dim largest As Variant, isLarger As Boolean, comparable As IComparable

    isRef = IsReferenceType
    For i = 1 To Count

        If isRef And IsEmpty(largest) Then
            Set largest = Item(i)
        ElseIf IsEmpty(largest) Then
            largest = Item(i)
        End If

        If TypeOf Item(i) Is IComparable Then
            Set comparable = Item(i)
            isLarger = comparable.CompareTo(largest) > 0
        Else
            isLarger = Item(i) > largest
        End If

        If isLarger Then
            If isRef Then
                Set largest = Item(i)
            Else
                largest = Item(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If isRef Then
        Set Max = largest
    Else
        Max = largest
    End If

End Function
```

These two functions allow a very readable sorting - because of what's going on here (adding & removing items), we're going to have to *fail fast*:

```vb
Public Sub Sort()
    If Not IsNumeric(First) And Not this.ItemTypeName = "String" And Not TypeOf First Is IComparer Then Err.Raise 5, ToString, "Invalid operation: Sort() requires a list of numeric or string values, or a list of objects implementing the IComparer interface."
    Dim i As Long, value As Variant, tmp As New List, minValue As Variant, isRef As Boolean

    isRef = IsReferenceType
    Do Until Count = 0

        If isRef Then
            Set minValue = Min
        Else
            minValue = Min
        End If

        tmp.Add minValue
        RemoveAt IndexOf(minValue)
    Loop

    Append tmp

End Sub

Public Sub SortDescending()
    If Not IsNumeric(First) And Not this.ItemTypeName = "String" And Not TypeOf First Is IComparer Then Err.Raise 5, ToString, "Invalid operation: SortDescending() requires a list of numeric or string values, or a list of objects implementing the IComparer interface."
    Dim i As Long, value As Variant, tmp As New List, maxValue As Variant, isRef As Boolean

    isRef = IsReferenceType
    Do Until Count = 0

        If isRef Then
            Set maxValue = Max
        Else
            maxValue = Max
        End If

        tmp.Add maxValue
        RemoveAt IndexOf(maxValue)
    Loop

    Append tmp

End Sub
```

#### The final touch

The rest is just trivial stuff:

```vb
Public Sub Remove(value As Variant)
    Dim index As Long
    index = IndexOf(value)
    If index <> -1 Then this.Encapsulated.Remove index
End Sub

Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = this.Encapsulated.Count
End Property

Public Sub Clear()
    Do Until Count = 0
        this.Encapsulated.Remove 1
    Loop
End Sub

Public Function First() As Variant
    If Count = 0 Then Exit Function
    If IsObject(Item(1)) Then
        Set First = Item(1)
    Else
        First = Item(1)
    End If
End Function

Public Function Last() As Variant
    If Count = 0 Then Exit Function
    If IsObject(Item(Count)) Then
        Set Last = Item(Count)
    Else
        Last = Item(Count)
    End If
End Function
```

One fun thing about `List<T>` is that it can be copied into an array just by calling `ToArray()` on it - we can do exactly that:

```vb
Public Function ToArray() As Variant()

    Dim result() As Variant
    ReDim result(1 To Count)

    Dim i As Long
    If Count = 0 Then Exit Function

    If IsReferenceType Then
        For i = 1 To Count
            Set result(i) = this.Encapsulated(i)
        Next
    Else
        For i = 1 To Count
            result(i) = this.Encapsulated(i)
        Next
    End If

    ToArray = result
End Function
```

That's all!

---

I'm using a few helper functions, here they are - they probably belong in some `StringHelpers` code module:

```vb
Public Function StringMatchesAny(ByVal string_source As String, find_strings() As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim find As String, i As Integer, found As Boolean

    For i = LBound(find_strings) To UBound(find_strings)

        find = CStr(find_strings(i))
        found = (string_source = find)

        If found Then Exit For
    Next

    StringMatchesAny = found

End Function

Public Function Coalesce(ByVal value As Variant, Optional ByVal value_when_null As Variant = 0) As Variant

    Dim return_value As Variant
    On Error Resume Next 'supress error handling

    If IsNull(value) Or (TypeName(value) = "String" And value = vbNullString) Then
        return_value = value_when_null
    Else
        return_value = value
    End If

    Err.Clear 'clear any errors that might have occurred
    On Error GoTo 0 'reinstate error handling

    Coalesce = return_value

End Function
```

---

### MyClass.cls

This implementation requires, when `T` is a reference type / object, that the class implements the `IComparable` interface in order to be sortable and for finding the index of a value. Here's how it's done - say you have a class called `MyClass` with a numeric or `String` property called `SomeProperty`:

```vb
Implements IComparable
Option Explicit

Private Function IComparable_CompareTo(other As Variant) As Integer
    Dim comparable As MyClass
    If Not TypeOf other Is MyClass Then Err.Raise 5

    Set comparable = other
    If comparable Is Nothing Then IComparable_CompareTo = 1: Exit Function

    If Me.SomeProperty < comparable.SomeProperty Then
        IComparable_CompareTo = -1
    ElseIf Me.SomeProperty > comparable.SomeProperty Then
        IComparable_CompareTo = 1
    End If

End Function

Private Function IComparable_Equals(other As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim comparable As MyClass
    If Not TypeOf other Is MyClass Then Err.Raise 5

    Set comparable = other
    IComparable_Equals = comparable.SomeProperty = Me.SomeProperty

End Function
```

The `List` can be used like this:

```vb
Dim myList As New List
myList.AddRange 1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345 ', 123456 would blow up because it's a Long
myList.SortDescending

Dim value As Variant
For Each value In myList
   Debug.Print Value
Next

Debug.Print myList.IndexOf(123) 'prints 3
Debug.Print myList.ToString & ".IsTypeSafe(""abc""): " & myList.IsTypeSafe("abc")
    ' prints List<Integer>.IsTypeSafe("abc"): false
```

Comment: @titol thanks! You may want to take a look at [this version](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/32618/23788) on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but I'd like to mention the following in addition to what's been discussed...

**Array Lists**

You can use an [ArrayList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.7.2), which is a weakly typed (uses objects, not strongly typed) linked list available in VBA. Here's some sample code demonstrating basic usage.

```
Sub ArrayListDemo()
    Dim MyArray(1 To 7) As String
    MyArray(1) = "A"
    MyArray(2) = "B"
    MyArray(3) = "B"
    MyArray(4) = "i"
    MyArray(5) = "x"
    MyArray(6) = "B"
    MyArray(7) = "C"
    Set L1 = ToList(MyArray)
    L1.Insert L1.LastIndexOf("B"), "Zz"
    Set L2 = L1.Clone
    L2.Sort
    L2.Reverse
    L2.Insert 0, "----------------"
    L2.Insert 0, "Sort and Reverse"
    L2.Insert 0, "----------------"
    L1.AddRange L2.Clone
    Set L3 = SnipArray(L1, 9, 3)
    Debug.Print "---- L1 Values ----"
    For Each obj In L1
        Debug.Print obj & " (L1 & L3 = " & L3.Contains(obj) & ")"
    Next
    Debug.Print "---- L3 Values ----"
    For Each obj In L3
        Debug.Print obj
    Next
End Sub
Function ToList(ByVal Arr As Variant) As Object
    Set ToList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    For Each Elm In Arr
      ToList.Add Elm
    Next Elm
End Function
Function SnipArray(ByVal ArrayList As Object, lower As Integer, length As Integer) As Object
    Set SnipArray = ArrayList.Clone
    lower = lower - 1
    upper = lower + length
    If upper < ArrayList.Count Then
        SnipArray.RemoveRange upper, (ArrayList.Count - upper)
    End If
    If lower > 0 Then
        SnipArray.RemoveRange 0, lower
    End If
End Function
```

**Dictionary**

Also, glad to see dictionary was mentioned. Here are a couple notes about how to use a dictionary in VBA and use it like a list:

```
Sub DictionaryDemo()
    'If you have a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime..."'
    Set D = New Dictionary
    'Else use this if you do not want to bother with adding a reference'
    Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'You can structure a dictionary as a zero based array like this'
    D.Add D.Count, "A"
    Debug.Print D(0)

    Set D = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Found this and was about to add ArrayLists as an option but alas you beat me to it... TWO YEARS AGO ;-) **NOTE** in the wild I have ran into issues installing .NET 2.0 & 3.5 (same install now) on Win7 and Win10 machines. You may have to `dism` in `cmd prompt` to get it to install correctly or else you may get a non-descript `Automation error`.

Comment: @GibralterTop ha, that's funny... alas, we were both too late to provide an appreciable answer, seeing as the original answer is a freakin novel that takes for ever to scroll through before you get here and are like, O, I can just use an ArrayList... seeing as the original question is 4 years old and you still came across it, the community might benefit from the question being framed for an updated answer and it won't be called a duplicate?... idk, people have different takes on that.

Comment: Upvoted for completeness, but to be fair the OP was after a VBA equivalent for `List<T>` i.e. a type-safe index-based collection. `ArrayList` is a .net type that works off `System.Object` and thus isn't type-safe and incurs a boxing penalty on value types, plus a marshaling penalty across COM/.net boundaries, and its overloaded methods make it rather hard to tell which overload you're invoking. I regret nothing of my *freakin novel*, except taking the lazy route of wrapping a `Collection` instead of using a much more efficient array. Cheers!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon You have a great answer. That wasn't my best choice of words. It is a very detailed answer, which is great, but it does bury the other answers way below it (the next answer is only found after about 80% of scrollbar travel). It's just a thought, but your answer would be a great post on a personal page, blog, or [Code project](https://www.codeproject.com/) that you could summarize here and link to. The casual reader would appreciate a summary of your answer while the link would provide implementation details.... also, thanks for the upvote! :)

Comment: Also, you are absolutely right about the limitations of ArrayList, it's great to point that out, but it's still a linked list and really is the closest readily available data structure in the VBA language to what the OP is asking. Of course you can build your own implementation of a linked list however you want (array backed, collection backed, etc.), but there's a difference between what the language offers versus how you can extend it.

Answer (score 2):

`List<T>` are **index based collection** which allows to attach any datatype to collection object which is not possible in VBA.

**Index based Collection for VBA**

- Arrays - On MSDN, [declaring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264224%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251519%28v=office.15%29.aspx). See also [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic/Arrays).

**Key-Value pair Collection for VBA**

- Collection - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251465%28v=office.15%29.aspx), [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic/Collections)
- Dictonary - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825%28v=office.15%29.aspx), [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic/Dictionaries)

Alternatively you may create a class library in C# and consume in VBA. Refer this [link](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/15/a-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-calling-a-net-library-from-excel/)

Comment: COM-visible C# code can't expose generic types, requires parameterless constructors, doesn't support method overloads and works across COM interop. That doesn't make it any simpler I find. And the way I'm seeing it, `List<T>` is an **object** and VBA's array isn't - that's how I say *the closest you get is a `Collection`*, since it's an object that exposes similar methods/functionality. But I agree, semantically speaking an array would be the closest thing. Actually a VBA array like `Dim a() As SomeClass` would be like a `List<SomeClass>` - I think OP is looking for the goodies/methods.

Comment: Actually `a() As SomeClass` would be much more like `SomeClass[]` than amything else...