# VBA: append one collection on to another like ".AddRange" in VB.NET

Tags: vba

Let's say I have a master collection that I want to add other collections to. I have some optional functions that return a collection and I want to append that to my existing collection. Is there a command to do that like the ".AddRange" in VB.NET ?

**VBA CODE EXAMPLE:**

```
Public Sub main()
    Dim masterCollection As Collection

    Do While addingThings
        If addManyThings Then
            masterCollection.AddRange functionReturnsCollection
        Else
            masterCollection.Add aThing
        End If
    Loop
End Sub

Private Function functionReturnsCollection() As Collection

End Function
```

Comment: By append do you simply mean add another item to the collection? In which case the method is .Add

Comment: @QHarr the `.Add` method would make the entire collection as one item in the master collection, instead of adding the children to the master, as desired. I don't want a collection of collections. I want to add a whole range of items to the master collection from the function that itself returns a collection of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Public Function AppendCollections( _
    Optional ByVal FirstCollection As Collection, _
    Optional ByVal SecondCollection As Collection, _
    Optional ByVal ThirdCollection As Collection _
        ) As Collection
    
    Dim ReturnCollection As Collection, i As Variant
    
    ' Start with an empty Collection
    Set ReturnCollection = New Collection
    
    ' Append the first Collection
    If Not FirstCollection Is Nothing Then
        For Each i In FirstCollection
            ReturnCollection.Add i
        Next i
    End If
    
    ' Append the second Collection
    If Not SecondCollection Is Nothing Then
        For Each i In SecondCollection
            ReturnCollection.Add i
        Next i
    End If
    
    'Append the third Collection
    If Not ThirdCollection Is Nothing Then
        For Each i In ThirdCollection
            ReturnCollection.Add i
        Next i
    End If
    
    ' Return the new Collection
    Set AppendCollections = ReturnCollection
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't think so with collections. You can access the method you mention via Systems Collection (.Net framework) and insertRange with ArrayList for example:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim a As Object, b As Object, i As Long
    Set a = CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue")
    a.Enqueue "D"
    a.Enqueue "E"

   Set b = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    With b
        .Add "A"
        .Add "B"
        .Add "C"
        .InsertRange 1, a
    End With

    For i = 0 To b.count - 1
        MsgBox b(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Perhaps there is a Class you could design to mimic this externally.

Comment: Are you saying I can import an object from the .NET framework in to VBA?

Comment: I am saying you can use some of the classes within System.Collections as shown above.

Comment: Did you progress this?

Comment: I need to refactor with an arraylist to test, but it's turtles all the way down so that refactor is across 3 modules.

Comment: Be interesting to see what you come up with :-)

Comment: This is amazing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148762/c-sharp-like-listt-in-vba

Comment: OMG...yes it is. Not surprising as it is mr guindon! I have upvoted both and will be having a good read of that later. Thanks so much for sharing. Though, I guess you can still use the .Net versions as above. Have a look through those as well. There are  [Lists - e.g. List of t](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx), SortedlLists, ArrayLists. HashTables....